# How to visualize fractals in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, fractals

This is the code for generating the fractals.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def makes(self, fractal):
    if (fractal == "SierpinskiTriangle"):
        SierpinskiTriangle(self.dimensions)
        for i in range(len(SierpinskiTriangle.verticies)):
            plotPoint(i, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
        for i in range(SierpinskiTriangle.numPoints):
            listVertices = SierpinskiTriangle.verticies
            randVert = randint(0, len(listVertices)-1)
            newVertexPoint = listVertices[randVert]
            m1 = Point.midpt(m1, newVertexPoint)
            self.plot(m1)

    elif (fractal == "SierpinskiCarpet"):
        SierpinskiCarpet(self.dimensions)
        for i in range(len(SierpinskiCarpet.verticies)):
            plotPoint(i, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
        for i in range(SierpinskiCarpet.numPoints):
            listVertices = SierpinskiCarpet
            randVert = randint(0, len(listVertices)-1)
            newVertexPoint = listVertices[randVert]
            m1 = Point.midpt(m1, newVertexPoint)
            self.plot(m1)

    else:
        Pentagon(self.dimensions)
        for i in range(len(Pentagon.verticies)):
            plotPoint(i, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
        for i in range(Pentagon.numPoints):
            listVertices = SierpinskiCarpet
            randVert = randint(0, len(listVertices)-1)
            newVertexPoint = listVertices[randVert]
            m1 = Point.midpt(m1, newVertexPoint)
            self.plot(m1)
```

At the end I don't know how to visualize the fractals. 
I think it has to do with matplot.lib but I'm not sure how

Comment: See [Generating a fractal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483238/generating-a-fractal-in-python) for another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `matplotplib` is primarily suited for plotting graphs, but you can draw points and polygons using it if you wish as well; see also: [How to draw a triangle using matplotlib.pyplot based on 3 dots (x,y) in 2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397105/how-to-draw-a-triangle-using-matplotlib-pyplot-based-on-3-dots-x-y-in-2d)

For instance, to compose a [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle) from polygons, and plot those polygons onto a figure:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MAX_LEVEL = 6


def sierpinski(p1, p2, p3, level=0):
    if level >= MAX_LEVEL:
        yield plt.Polygon([p1, p2, p3], color='red')
        return

    yield from sierpinski(p1, (p1+p2) / 2, (p1+p3) / 2, level+1)
    yield from sierpinski((p1+p2) / 2, p2, (p2+p3) / 2, level+1)
    yield from sierpinski((p1+p3) / 2, (p2+p3) / 2, p3, level+1)


plt.figure()
plt.scatter([0, 0, 10, 10], [0, 10, 0, 10], color='blue')

for patch in sierpinski(
        np.array([1.0, 1.0]), np.array([9.0, 1.0]), np.array([5.0, 9.0])):
    plt.gca().add_patch(patch)

plt.show()
```

The above code generates the following image output for me:

[image: matplotlib output]